# PostgreSQL Query - how to subtract timestamps and format durations (with builitin functions or otherweise)

Tags: postgresql, query, timestamp, format, interval

I am looking for a solution to a problem with a select statement where I am trying to display the sleep duration.

#### Sleep Table

[image: here is my columns from sleep TABLE]

Here is the select statement I have so far:

```
select wakeuptime,hour from
        (
            select patientid, 
                   sum(s.duration) as hour, 
                   Date(s.wake_up_time) as wakeuptime 
            from sleep s
            where patientid = pid::varchar
            group by patientid, Date(s.wake_up_time) 
            order by Date(s.wake_up_time) desc
        ) s
        order by s.wakeuptime asc;
```

I need to calculate `Sum (wake_up_time - time_to_bed)` where it should convert minutes into hours for example `55mins + 15mins` should return `1hr 10mins`.

Comment: Where does `duration` column from? And how is it different than `wake_up_time - time_to_bed`?

Comment: Also, as a final point, could you please not upload images to dba.se for the reasons outlined in [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530).

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started (a fiddle with the code below is available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=37103c31fc67fa4cb20f534a0f330a26)):

```
CREATE TABLE sleep
(
  patient_id  SMALLINT    NOT NULL,
   sleep_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
  time_to_bed TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
  wakeup_time TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
  
  CONSTRAINT ttb_lt_wt_ck CHECK (time_to_bed < wakeup_time)
);
```

populate it with sample records:

```
INSERT INTO sleep VALUES
(1, '2021-04-05 13:57:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '2021-04-05 13:57:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '2021-04-05 15:34:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ),
(1, '2021-04-04 14:01:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '2021-04-05 14:01:30'::TIMESTAMPTZ, '2021-04-05 16:26:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ);
```

Then run:

```
SELECT
    (EXTRACT(HOUR   FROM (wakeup_time - time_to_bed))) AS hours,
    (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (wakeup_time - time_to_bed))) AS minutes,
    (EXTRACT(SECOND FROM (wakeup_time - time_to_bed))) AS seconds,
    
    (EXTRACT(HOUR   FROM (wakeup_time - time_to_bed))) || ' hours, '      ||
    (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (wakeup_time - time_to_bed))) || ' minutes and ' ||
    (EXTRACT(SECOND FROM (wakeup_time - time_to_bed))) || ' seconds' AS "Total"
FROM sleep;
```

Result:

```
hours   minutes seconds                  Total
    1        37       0   1 hours, 37 minutes and 0 seconds
    2        24      30   2 hours, 24 minutes and 30 seconds
```

To get sums:

```
SELECT 
  SUM (wakeup_time - time_to_bed) AS "Total", 
  EXTRACT(HOUR   FROM SUM(wakeup_time - time_to_bed)) AS hours,
  EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM SUM(wakeup_time - time_to_bed)) AS minutes,
  EXTRACT(SECOND FROM SUM(wakeup_time - time_to_bed)) AS seconds
FROM sleep
GROUP BY patient_id;
```

Result:

```
   Total    hours   minutes seconds
04:01:30        4         1      30
```

You could also make use of the [`JUSTIFY_INTERVAL()`](https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/justify_interval-function.php) function as follows (thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name for that one!):

```
SELECT 
  JUSTIFY_INTERVAL(wakeup_time - time_to_bed) AS "Interval"
FROM sleep;
```

Result:

```
Interval
01:37:00
02:24:30
```

and

```
SELECT 
  JUSTIFY_INTERVAL(SUM (wakeup_time - time_to_bed)) AS "Sum of intervals"
FROM sleep
GROUP BY patient_id;
```

Result:

```
Sum of intervals
        04:01:30
```

A couple of points to note.

- please **always** include your server version in your question - the answer(s) can vary according to this!
- also, when asking a question of this nature, please construct a fiddle with your table structures and sample data - this provides a single source of truth for the question and prevents duplication of effort by those who answer. Help us to help you!

p.s. welcome to dba.se!

Comment: You probably want to apply `justify_interval()` before doing the `extract()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - done! Thanks for  your input on that one! I'll have to peruse the manual again... missed that one - it's handy!